# create and update sale order in magento using soap api in python

Tags: python, magento, soap

How we can create and update sale order in magento using soap api by python script?

I coudnt find any api for sale order export to magento.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: This is all that I was able to find https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6754/order-csv-export-what-fields-does-it-export and http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/slandsbek/extension/1350/simple-order-export